# Dynamic mapping of Single Table Inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have old database that I try to migrate into Doctrine ORM.

Our database looks like this:

```
product_tbl
```

| id | name | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product-1 | Name | 1010 |
| product-2 | Name 2 | 1010 |
| special-case-1 | Promo product | 1020 |

```
type_tbl
```

| id | className |
| --- | --- |
| 1010 | Product |
| 1020 | SpecialProduct |

```php
class Product extends Entity {
    private string $id;
    private string $name;
    private int $type_id;
}

class SpecialProduct extends Product {
}
```

So as you can see we have `type_id` that is dynamic and is taken from different table.

Seems like I could translate this into Doctrine [Single Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance), but for that I need to manually write all cases:

```php
#[Entity]
#[InheritanceType('SINGLE_TABLE')]
#[DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'type_id', type: 'int')]
#[DiscriminatorMap([1010 => Product::class, 1020 => SpecialProduct::class])]
class Product {
    // ..entity information..
}
```

How can I make this mapping dynamic (on build or similar) and keep rest of mappings as PHP Attributes?

Comment: Just an idea: Is there such a high amount of classes? What about creating the adequate child class from the constructor by calling a required method? It is not abstract :)

Comment: @Blackbam Yes, there is plenty of classes. But what you mean _creating child classes from constructor_?

Comment: Instead of using Doctrines' DiscriminatorMap you could solve this within the code, this is what i suggested.